# How to forward an e-mail and add the original sender to Reply-To?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, forwarding, headers

When forwarding an e-mail how to configure e-mail clients to put the address of the original e-mail sender (`From:`) to the `Reply-To:` (or different) header?

I am looking mainly for a solution for Thunderbird and possibly MS Outlook. Solutions for other e-mail clients would be welcome too. Unfortunately I did not find a solution for Thunderbird besides writing a new extension. Of course I am looking for an automated solution I know that the `Reply-To:` header can be filled manually.

The story behind this need is below.

### Situation

We are using a helpdesk system ([OTRS](http://www.otrs.com/)) and there is a problem that sometimes customers send a request to a personal mailbox instead to the helpdesk. I am looking for a solution how to manually forward those e-mails to the helpdesk address from the personal mailboxes.

### Standard solutions do not work

Unfortunately standard forward operation puts the address of the forwarding user to the `From:` header. This is very uncomfortable because in OTRS the customer has to be changed manually and even then the reply puts the forwarder into `To:` and the original customer only to `Cc:` which is wrong.

E-mail clients usually allow redirect or bounce function which is similar to forward but the original sender is kept in the `From:` header. Unfortunately our mail server does not allow sending e-mails as other users and it is very unlikely that this limitation will be removed.

### Informing helpdesk about the original sender

Fortunately OTRS is customizable to a great extent. It can parse e-mail headers and according to them perform certain actions but there is no standard e-mail header which would keep the original sender and it seems that major e-mail clients do not use any non-standard one for this.

It seems very logical to put the original sender to the `Reply-To:` header so this is the reason for the question at the beginning of my post.